How can I achieve the same output in lm() and fixest feols()? (TWFE)
I'm trying to use the fixest package feols() to estimate a TWFE model. I know how to do it using lm(), but I can't get the same output as lm().
I'm trying to estimate a TWFE model like this:

Here's the data:
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~state, ~time, ~outcome, ~treat2,
      1L,    1L,       9L,      0L,
      1L,    2L,      12L,      0L,
      1L,    3L,      15L,      0L,
      1L,    4L,      18L,      0L,
      1L,    5L,      21L,      0L,
      1L,    6L,      24L,      0L,
      1L,    7L,      27L,      0L,
      1L,    8L,      30L,      0L,
      1L,    9L,      33L,      0L,
      1L,   10L,      36L,      0L,
      2L,    1L,      11L,      0L,
      2L,    2L,      14L,      0L,
      2L,    3L,      17L,      0L,
      2L,    4L,      20L,      0L,
      2L,    5L,      23L,      0L,
      2L,    6L,      28L,      1L,
      2L,    7L,      33L,      1L,
      2L,    8L,      38L,      1L,
      2L,    9L,      43L,      1L,
      2L,   10L,      48L,      1L
  )

library(fixest)

# Mod 1
lm(outcome ~ treat2 + factor(state) + factor(time), 
             data = dat) |> 
  summary()

# Mod 2
feols(outcome ~ treat2 | state + time, data = dat)

and here is the output from the two models:
Call:
lm(formula = outcome ~ treat2 + factor(state) + factor(time), 
    data = dat)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
    -2      0      0      0      2 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       9.000      1.225   7.348 8.01e-05 ***
treat2            6.000      1.414   4.243 0.002827 ** 
factor(state)2    2.000      1.000   2.000 0.080516 .  
factor(time)2     3.000      1.581   1.897 0.094350 .  
factor(time)3     6.000      1.581   3.795 0.005276 ** 
factor(time)4     9.000      1.581   5.692 0.000459 ***
factor(time)5    12.000      1.581   7.589 6.37e-05 ***
factor(time)6    13.000      1.732   7.506 6.89e-05 ***
factor(time)7    17.000      1.732   9.815 9.76e-06 ***
factor(time)8    21.000      1.732  12.124 1.98e-06 ***
factor(time)9    25.000      1.732  14.434 5.19e-07 ***
factor(time)10   29.000      1.732  16.743 1.64e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

OLS estimation, Dep. Var.: outcome
Observations: 20
Fixed-effects: state: 2,  time: 10
Standard-errors: Clustered (state) 
       Estimate Std. Error      t value  Pr(>|t|)    
treat2        6   1.16e-15 5.165983e+15 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
RMSE: 1     Adj. R2: 0.979437
          Within R2: 0.692308

The treat2 coefficient is the same (6), which is reassuring, but is it possible to get the all  the coefficients that lm outputs? I guess you would call them the FE coefficients.
